# Is it possible to change shell using bashrc when assigned a nologin default shell?

Tags: login, bashrc

i have assigned a /sbin/nologin shell to a user while creating that user (specifying -s option in useradd), if this user logs in using SFTP and changes his .bashrc file, will he be able to change his shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the user can't over-ride /sbin/nologin via .bashrc.

.bashrc is run by the bash shell. nologin doesn't execute it, so modifications to .bashrc should be irrelevant.